# What data structure is prefered instead of manipulating multiple vectors

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stl

I have implemented a class that makes computations on images. The processing is being done on a subset of the given images (lets say 100 out of 1000) at a time and each image takes a different number of iterations to finish. The processing uses GPUs and therefore it is not possible to use all the images at once. When the processing of an image is finished then this image is removed and another one is added. So I am using three different vectors `image_outcome`, `image_index`, `image_operation` to keep infromations about the images:

1. The `image_outcome` is a `std::vector<float>` and each of its elements is a value that is used as a criterion to decide when the image is finished.
2. The `image_index` is a `std::vector<int>` that holds the index of image in the original dataset.
3. The `image_operation` is a `std::vector<MyEnumValue>` that holds the operation that is used to update the `image_outcome`. Is of an `enum` type and its value is one of many possible operations.

There are also two functions, one to remove the finished images and one to add as many images as removed (if there are still enough in the input).

1. The `remove_images()` function takes all three matrices and the image matrix and removes the elements using the `std::vector.erase()`.
2. The `add_images()` takes again the three matrices and the image matrix adds new images and the relevant information to the vectors.

Because I am using an `erase()` on each vector with the same index (and also a similar way to add) I was thinking to:

1. Use a private `struct` that has three vectors (nested struct).
2. Use a private `class` that is implemented using three vectors (nested class).
3. Use a different data-structure other than vec.

A hight-level example of the code can be fund below:

```
class ComputationClass {
  public:
    // the constructor initializes the member variables
    ComputationClass();
    void computation_algorithm(std::vector<cv::Mat> images);

  private:
    // member variables which define the algorithms parameters
    // add_images() and remove_images() functions take more than these
    // arguments, but I only show the relevant here
    add_images(std::vector<float>&, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<MyEnumValue>&);
    remove_images(std::vector<float>&, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<MyEnumValue>&);
};

void ComputationClass::computation_algorithm(std::vector<cv::Mat> images) {
  std::vector<float> image_output; 
  std::vector<int> image_index;
  std::vector<MyEnumValue> image_operation;

  add_images(image_output, image_index, image_operation);

  while (there_are_still_images_to_process) {
    // make computations by updating the image_output vector
    // check which images finished computing
    remove_images(image_output, image_index, image_operation);
    add_images(image_output, image_index, image_operation);
  }
}
```

Comment: A structure containing a `float`, an `int` and a `MyEnumValue`, then a vector of that structure?

Comment: Data that is associated together, should stay together, or you'll eventually have a hard time maintaining it. It'll reduce cache misses too.

Answer (score 2):

I think, instead of a struct with 3 vectors, a single vector of user-defined objects would work better.

```
std::vector<MyImage> images;

class MyImage {
    Image OImage; // the actual image
    float fOutcome;
    int dIndex;
    MyEnumValue eOperation;
    bool getIsDone() {
        return fOutcome > 0; // random condition
    }
}
```

You can add to vector or erase from vector with a condition

```
if( (*it).getIsDone() ) {
    VMyVector.erase( it );
}
```

In my opinion, maintaining 3 vectors that go parallel is easy to make mistakes and hard to modify.

Comment: I suggest to use pointers, it will be more efficient. 

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyImage>> images;

Comment: 3 vectors could be faster.

Comment: Should I implement this class inside the other class as it is going to be included on another project and I want to provide the best possible encapsulation.

Comment: @user5438960 I think you should implement this class in the same place where you have the vector<MyImage>. If you want the best possible encapsulation, make all the variables as private and write modifiers and accessors as public. If your "best possible encapsulation" means something more specific, please explain more.

Comment: @KrzysztofBargieł I think I personally don't like unnecessary dynamic alloation. whatever in shared_ptr will be dynamically allocated and whatever that's inserted into a vector will be dynamically allocated.

Comment: @KrzysztofBargieł In addition, accessors( at(), [] ) will return a reference to an element and std::move() can be used to insert and, I think, delete from the vector